# Could you make it blink?

Tags: javascript, html, caret

I found this code but I could not figure out how to make the cursor blink

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.05em solid #32CD32}";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```html
<a href="pages/guitar.html" target="_self">
  <h5 class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "fundamental", "simplified" ]'>
    <span class="wrap blink-caret"></span>
  </h5>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you paste some code in a google doc, then shared the doc and posted the public link, instead of, you know, just pasting the code in your question? Why?

Comment: Jeremy Thille
the platform keeps preventing me from posting it because of errors related to the indenting. I couldn't figure out where the problem was. I tried indenting it to the best of my ability, but no luck. I shared a txt file

Comment: Please remove all these comments containing chunks of code. You can _edit_ your original question to add code. I did it for you and created a code snippet.

Comment: I was wondering how that happened, thank you. were u able to make the cursor blink too?

Comment: I'm having a look at it. As it seems, the "cursor" is actually a CSS `border-right : 0.05em solid #32CD32`. There must be an easy way to make it blink using CSS animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to do it with a CSS blinking right-border.

It blinks every 0.5s, however, the `<span>` gets reconstructed every time a letter is typed, so the CSS timer resets. You can see the cursor blinking when the letters pause typing and wait for more than 0.5s.

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.typewrite > .wrap {
  animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  border-right: solid 3px #32CD32;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="pages/guitar.html" target="_self">
  <h5 class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "fundamental", "simplified" ]'>
    <span class="wrap blink-caret"></span>
  </h5>
</a>
```

Comment: you are mastermind, thank you. How did u get good at coding?

Comment: By waking up at 5am every day for years to study, and by making every possible mistake... If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thank u anyways, they closed it by the way, and I cannot mark it as solved